# HTML loader div not visible on click of button

Tags: jquery, html, loader

I am trying to show a loader symbol on click of a button and hide it once all the actions are executed. However, the loader is never visible.

Below is the code.
HTML code:

```
<div id="loader">
    <table height='100%' width='100%' style='cursor:wait'>
        <tr>
            <td style='vertical-align: middle' align='center'>
                <img alt='' src='/_imgs/AdvFind/progress.gif' height="25px" />
                <div /><span style='font-family:Tahoma,Arial;font-size: 11px;'></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
  $('#btnLoadData').bind('click', OnLoadDataClicked);
var OnLoadDataClicked = function () {
        showLoadingSymbol();
       //Some logic, which can take 30-40 sec
       hideLoadingSymbol();
};
```

Loader never gets shown on the UI. Can someone please help?

Comment: what is in `showLoadingSymbol` and `hideLoadingSymbol` functions?

Comment: Can you show code inside `showLoadingSymbol` fucntion?

Answer (score 1):

First, what is this:

```
style='cursor:wait'
```

could it be overwriting your width/height ?
Second, Check that

```
src='/_imgs/AdvFind/progress.gif'
```

is the correct path
Also, I would recommend being consistent with your single/double codes in html

Comment: image path is correct. if I comment hideLoadingSymbol(), loader is visible on UI. I have modified the code for this post. No need to focus on things which are less important.